# Как загрузить в Adonis JS большой файл, разбитый на chunk?

Tags: javascript, blob, adonis.js

Я делаю серверную часть для сайта на фреймверке Adonis JS.
Мне поставили задачу грузить большие файлы, для решение этой задачи я решил использовать загрузку файла чанками.
Я нашел готовый код для клиентской части, он вроде бы работает.

Вот код на стороне клиента: https://codepen.io/chaly7500/pen/YzQyZNR

Код на стороне сервера:

```
//routes.ts

apiGroup('v1', 'files', Route.group(async () => {
  Route.post('upload', 'Files/UploadController.index')
}))
```

```
//UploadController.ts
'use strict'
import {HttpContextContract} from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext";
import MediaRepositories from "App/Repositories/MediaRepositories";

export default class UploadController {
   public async index({request}:HttpContextContract){

     const file = request.file('file')
     // console.log(file)
     return await MediaRepositories.createMedia(file)
   }
}
```

```
//MediaRepositories.ts

'use strict'
import Application from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/Application";


export default class MediaRepositories {


  static async createMedia(file) {
    await file.move(Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels'));
  }

  static async updateMediaById(){

  }

  static async updateMediaByIds(){

  }
}
```

После загрузки на сервере у меня есть файл blob
И при изминении файла blob на blob.png изображение ломается

Реализоавывал ли кто то загрузку больших файлов используя AdonisJS?

Или как правильно конвертировать blob файл в изображение или видео?

**Основной вопрос:**
Как загружать в adonis больгие файлы и не получать ошибку request timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

Я смог решить проблему загрузки с помощью этой библиотеки https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-chunked.

```
//UploadController.ts
'use strict'
import {HttpContextContract} from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext";
import parseJson from "parse-json";
import MediaRepositories from "App/Repositories/MediaRepositories";
export default class UploadController {
  public async index({request}:HttpContextContract){
    
    const file = await request.file('file')
    const chunkMetaDataStr = await request.input('chunkMetadata');
    const chunkMetaData = await parseJson(chunkMetaDataStr);
    return await MediaRepositories.createMedia(file, chunkMetaData)

  }
}
```

```
// MediaRepositories.ts
'use strict'
import Application from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/Application";
import FileChunked from "file-chunked";
import * as fs from "fs";
import Media from "App/Models/Media";
import Env from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Env'

export default class MediaRepositories {


  static async createMedia(file, chunkMetaData) {

    await file?.move(Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels/' + chunkMetaData.FileGuid + '/tmp_chunks'));

    await FileChunked.upload({
      chunkStorage: Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels/' + chunkMetaData.FileGuid), // where the uploaded file(chunked file in this case) are saved
      uploadId: chunkMetaData.FileGuid,
      chunkIndex: chunkMetaData.Index,
      totalChunksCount: chunkMetaData.TotalCount,
      filePath: file?.filePath,
    });

    if (chunkMetaData.Index == (chunkMetaData.TotalCount - 1)) {
     
        fs.copyFileSync(Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels/' + chunkMetaData.FileGuid + '/tmp_chunks/' + file.clientName),
          Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels/' + chunkMetaData.FileGuid + '/tmp_chunks/' + chunkMetaData.FileName));

 
    }

    
  }
}
```